# add condition in query

Tags: php, laravel

Guys. i have 1 to many relations with organization with the conference. and also I have currency, what i am try to do here is filter products by search using price.

### controller

```
$Conferences=Confrence::with('organization')
 ->when(request(['start_price','end_price']), function($query){
     // how to add condition ???   
    if($query->organization->currency->symbol==='ETB'){
         return $query->where('confrence_price','>=', request('start_price'))
                      ->where('confrence_price','<=',request('end_price'));
    }else{
    return $query->where('birr_currency_conference','>=', request('start_price'))
                ->where('birr_currency_conference','<=',request('end_price'));
   }
 })
```

Comment: did you use ->get(); after the all of these?
add this to end of the everything. 
dd($Conferences->get());

Comment: Please try your query first, looks like you have many potential issues there: missing `get()` + you are calling `organization->currency->symbol` on a `QueryBuilder` . And what condition are you trying to add?

Comment: guys get() is not problem i writed below code. the issue is how to i sink 1 step deper, b/c the request all in ETB currency and i have some $, so how to check it like ```->whereHas('organization', function($q){ return $q->where('currency',1)->when($request(['start_price, 'end_price]), function($q){ ....}})```